# How can i send a byte daha which is greater than 127 in Java?

Tags: java, byte

I am developing an RFID reader application using Java. The RFID reader's message type has to start with 0xA0. It is obligatory. It is represented as 160 in decimal form. But in java byte values can not be greater than 127.

How do I solve this?

Comment: A byte is 8-bits, you can make those 8 bits anything you want and you can say that 0xA0 is 160, or -96 or it could be you representation for one million, i.e. it can mean anything you want, it is just 8 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just send `(byte) 0xa0`. Yes, as a Java `byte` it will be negative, but it will still have the right *bit* pattern, which is all the RFID will care about.

Basically, you rarely need to think of bytes as *numbers* as such - it's more usual to think of them as sequences of bits, which happen to map to numbers.

For example, suppose you have a file consisting of a single byte, with the bits `11111111`. If you read the data for that in Java, you'll get a byte of -1. If you read the data for that in C#, you'll get a byte of 255. It's the same data, just viewed in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 1):

You can put 0xA0 in a byte, it will just be treated as negative if you do arithmetic. If you don't do arithmetic, all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

Data is data. In java, a byte with the value of 0xA0 will be a negative number, but an int with the same value will be a positive value... It's all about interpretation.

You can write/put the byte 0xA0 to your stream/byte[] and it shouldn't be a problem